# Modeling fluid flow in extremely small pores (or channels) compared to the component

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, flow, navier-stokes

I want to model a non-wetting fluid flowing into tiny pores of a component using Navier-Stokes.

Just for you to visualize, say I have a 2D rectangular component of dimensions $L*W$, and within that component I have two porous channels of size $D$, and $D << L$, say we have a 1 micron pore for a component size in meters.

If $D$ were of the order of $L$, meshing is easy and I can do CFD on the domain. How do we handle extremely small channels as compared to the component?

My actual problem is similar, I have a component with micron sized connected pores, and I want to model the fluid flow inside those pores. Is there a standard approach to model such systems (like a homogenized approach, etc.?)

Comment: If $D\ll L$ and the interactions on such a scale are important to you, then you probably will have a very big mesh (unless you have an adaptive mesh solver set up).

Comment: Do you know the internal geometry of the pores, and their interconnection?  Are you displacing a gas in the pores by a liquid, or is it just steady fluid flow through the porous medium?  Are you familiar with Darcy's law?  You do realize that,, in this system, the flow is purely viscous,, and that inertial effects are negligible, right?

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes. I do know the pore structure, and I am displacing a gas in the pores by a liquid.

I am aware of the porous flow. For instance, I can get an effective permeability and apply Darcy's law, but how to include say surface tension effects of the liquid, closed connections, or tortuosity of the channels. Are there references that deal with these effects in a continuum sense ?

Comment: For surface tension, Google "capillary pressure."  I don't know of anyone that has modeled flow through a detailed pore geometry, even for single phase flow.